# Compare AD against CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I am trying to create a script that will compare our AD against all the users in a CSV. Our HR department has the master database for all staff but when they make changes they rarely inform us so they now export all users from the HR database to a CSV.

I need to compare this against our AD and amend anyone that has been found to have changed or any new staff.

I have the below script but it just outputs all staff, I only want the staff that have changed or new staff that are not in AD to be emailed.

```psh
write-host "Using default CSV file or C:\scripts\csv\StaffChanges.csv"
$StaffCSVUPath = "C:\scripts\csv\StaffChanges.csv"

$logfile = "C:\scripts\logs\ADvsCMIS.csv"

if(test-path $logfile) {
    remove-item $logfile -force
}

function Email {
    #Send an email, called with recipient email address and message body
    param(
        [string] $emailaddress="",
        [string] $bodymsg=""
    )
    $bodymsg += "<p>"
    $bodymsg += Get-Content($logfile)
    Send-MailMessage -To $emailaddress -From "email@domain.co.uk" -Subject "(AD-CMIS_errors) Errors found between Active Directory and CMIS" -Body $bodymsg -BodyAsHTML -SMTPServer "exchserver"
}


function CheckOutputFile {
    #Called with folder\filename and type of file
    param(
        [string]$outputfilename = "",
        [string]$type = ""
    )
    if(test-path($outputfilename)) {
    } else {
        write-host "Creating $outputfilename"
        $msg = "Forename,Surname,Username,ID"
        $msg | out-file($outputfilename)
    }
}

#Snap-ins needed to use the commands within the script
if((Get-pssnapin -Name Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.E2010 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null){Add-PSSnapin  Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010}
if((Get-pssnapin -Name Quest.activeroles.admanagement -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)-eq $null){Add-pssnapin Quest.activeroles.admanagement}

#import users from csv file
$users = (import-Csv $StaffCSVUpath)
$count=0
$countAD=0

Get-QADUser -searchroot "domain/Users/Staff" -SizeLimit 0 -includedproperties employeeid,displayname | ForEach-Object ($_.samaccountname) {
    $found = 0
    $countAD+=1
    ForEach ($user in $users) {
        $count+=1
        $inital = $user.forename.substring(0,1)
        $name = $user.forename+" "+$user.surname
        $dispname = $inital+" "+$user.surname
        if ($user.id -eq $_.employeeid) {
            if ($user.surname -eq $_.lastname) {
                if ($inital -eq $_.firstname) {
                    if ($name -eq $_.name) {
                        if ($dispname -eq $_.displayname) {
                            $found = 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if ($found -eq 1){break}
    }
    if ($found -eq 0) {
        if(($_.company -ne "testing") -band ($_.company -ne "service")) {
            CheckOutputFile $logfile "LOG"
            $msg = "<p>" + $_.firstname +" " + $_.lastname + " " + $_.samaccountname + " "+$_.employeeid +"<p>"
            $msg | Out-File $logfile -append
        }
    }
}

if (test-path $logfile) {
    #If there is anything to report
    write-host "Emailing Log file to ict"
    #Email file if $outputB exists
    $email = "email@domain.co.uk"
    $body = "Action Required: The users below do not exist within HR.  Contact HR Data manager to resolve issue, delete users manually if required."
    #email ict
    Email $email $body
}
```

Comment: Make them store UPNs in their base, then you can find a user quickly by its UPN. Thankfully UPNs are usually equal to emails, although it might not be exactly the case with you. And be warned as you're dealing with sensitive data, "amending" new staff in AD can potentially provide an inside data leak as an authorized user.

Comment: Just a quick note, the CSV file only contains the following fields:- ID, Firstname, Surname. The ID is usually just the user initials but is unique for every user.

Comment: If you have a way to map ID to `sAMAccountName`, `userPrincipalName` or `cn` or vice versa, do just that, and update attributes according to data in the CSV. I say do not create new users or delete/disable old ones. If not, devise a way to do this, you can use other attributes if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get it working by changing the search fields

```
    if($user.firstname -eq $_.firstname)
    if($user.surname -eq $_.sn)
    if($user.ID -eq $_.employeeID)
```

This now checks AD against the CSV, emails any discrepancies and excludes any emails with the firstname "test" or "careers"

```
write-host "Using default CSV file or C:\scripts\csv\StaffChanges.csv"
$StaffCSVUPath = "C:\scripts\csv\StaffChanges.csv"

$logfile = "C:\scripts\logs\ADvsHR.csv"

if(test-path $logfile) {
    remove-item $logfile -force
}

function Email {
    #Send an email, called with recipient email address and message body
    param(
        [string] $emailaddress="",
        [string] $bodymsg=""
    )
    $bodymsg += "<p>"
    $bodymsg += Get-Content($logfile)
    Send-MailMessage -To $emailaddress -From "email@domain.co.uk" -Subject "(AD-CMIS_errors) Errors found between Active Directory and CMIS" -Body $bodymsg -BodyAsHTML -SMTPServer "exchserver"
}


function CheckOutputFile {
    #Called with folder\filename and type of file
    param(
        [string]$outputfilename = "",
        [string]$type = ""
    )
    if(test-path($outputfilename)) {
    } else {
        write-host "Creating $outputfilename"
        $msg = "Forename,Surname,Username,ID"
        $msg | out-file($outputfilename)
    }
}

#Snap-ins needed to use the commands within the script
if((Get-pssnapin -Name Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.E2010 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null){Add-PSSnapin  Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010}
if((Get-pssnapin -Name Quest.activeroles.admanagement -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)-eq $null){Add-pssnapin Quest.activeroles.admanagement}

#import users from csv file
$users = (import-Csv $StaffCSVUpath)
$count=0
$countAD=0

Get-QADUser -searchroot "domain/Users/Staff" -SizeLimit 0 -includedproperties employeeid,displayname | ForEach-Object ($_.samaccountname) {
    $found = 0
    $countAD+=1
    ForEach ($user in $users) {
        $count+=1
        if ($user.firstname -eq $_.firstname) {
            if ($user.surname -eq $_.sn) {
                if ($user.ID -eq $_.employeeID) {
                            $found = 1
                }
            }
        }
        if ($found -eq 1){break}
    }
    if ($found -eq 0) {
        if(($_.firstname -ne "careers") -band ($_.firstname -ne "test")) {
            CheckOutputFile $logfile "LOG"
            $msg = "<p>" + $_.firstname +" " + $_.lastname + " "+$_.employeeid +"<p>"
            $msg | Out-File $logfile -append
        }
    }
}

if (test-path $logfile) {
    #If there is anything to report
    write-host "Emailing Log file to ict"
    #Email file if $outputB exists
    $email = "email@domain.co.uk"
    $body = "Action Required: The users below do not exist within HR.  Contact HR Data manager to resolve issue, delete users manually if required."
    #email ict
    Email $email $body
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the Quest AD cmdlets, so my answer will be based on the built-in ones. Also, I'm going to assume that the (unique) employee ID for any given employee is not going to change and that there are no user accounts with an empty `employeeId` attribute.

First, prepare your data like this:

```psh
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$hrUsers = @{}
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv' |
  select id, firstname, surname,
         @{n='inital';e={$_.forename.substring(0,1)}},
         @{n='name';e={$_.forename+" "+$_.surname}},
         @{n='dispname';e={$_.forename.substring(0,1)+" "+$_.surname}} |
  % { $hrUsers[$_.id] = $_ }

$adUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Property employeeid |
           ? { 'testing', 'service' -notcontains $_.company }
```

This creates a hashtable mapping each employee ID to the object with the respective user's attributes (including the derivative attributes `initial`, `name`, and `dispname`) and a list of AD users (excluding service and test accounts).

With the above you can determine new users like this:

```psh
$employeeIDs = @($adUsers | select -Expand employeeId)
$hrUsers.Values | ? { $employeeIDs -notcontains $_.id }
```

obsolete accounts like this:

```psh
$adUsers | ? { $hrUsers.Keys -notcontains $_.employeeId }
```

and modified users like this:

```psh
$adUsers | ? {
  $hrUsers[$_.employeeid].surname -ne $_.lastname -or
  $hrUsers[$_.employeeid].inital -ne $_.firstname -or
  $hrUsers[$_.employeeid].name -ne $_.name -or
  $hrUsers[$_.employeeid].dispname -ne $_.displayname
}
```